# How to send an email with a distinctive attributes for the server to determine?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, security

**Scenario:**

1. I build a simple web based app for mobile that needs to interact with server via mail client. The Web App is in PHP.
2. In the Web App there's a link opening a mail client of mobile phone. It would be using the `mailto:` function and the code will look something like this
   (`<a href="mailto:linkrequest@system.com">Request Link</a>`)
3. This link would open the default mail client to send an empty message to the server.
4. The user needs to use mail client to send the empty message so it would just use it's default email of the user and to avoid making the user type for it's email.
5. After the server received the empty message it will automatically respond to the user with the data from the database.

The `mailto:` function will be located inside a webapp. When sending the message to the server it needs to be unique (*probably put some encrypted code*) so there would be a distinctive attributes on the mail that is going to the server. So with that distinctive attribute server can now determine which email it would respond automatically and would not respond.

What solution do you suggest to my problem?

[image]

Comment: you could use a dynamic email address and a catch all on he server.

Comment: seems like a good idea too. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify additional attributes in the email by embedding them in the mailto url like this (the line breaks are here only readability and you won't need to insert them into the URL):

```
mailto:linkrequest@system.com
?subject=MobileUser
&X-Mailer=Baluba
&body=MobileUser!%0D%0ABla!
```

Comment: For more info you can check out [http://email.about.com/cs/standards/a/mailto_js.htm]

Comment: Is "X-Mailer=Baluba" the additional attribute ?

Comment: X-Mailer is used to describe the mail sending software http://www.example-code.com/vb/X-Mailer.asp

Comment: Btw, Thank you for your answer. would you recommend to put the distinction on an attachment? let say an invisible ".gif" file.

Comment: Invisible image attachments are handy to keep track of whether the email was opened by the user. I wouldn't recommend attaching that unless you want to keep track of whether the user saw the email

Comment: Please up vote or rate my answer whenever you get chance Thanks!

Comment: I'm just planning to use the invisible ".gif" so server could determine it's special. I don't know if this would work though... thanks!